# How can I use a URL in a route?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want people to be able to visit:

`http://example.com/report/http://yourdomain.com`

At that URL my angular2 app will generate a report on the users domain.  I want it to work like this so a non-technical user can type it in easily.

In my app I am using this route:

```
{ path: 'report/:url', component: MyReportComponent }
```

This does not work if there are any forward slash or period in the route.

If I encode the colon and forward slashes I can use `Navigate(encodedUrl)` and it will work but if I try to visit the encoded path directly then it won't work unless I remove the period.

For my report I would prefer to have the protocol but I have found even trying to get `http://example.com/report/yourdomain.com` doesn't work because of the period.

If I do `http://example.com/report;yourdomain.com` then it works if I move to it by Navigate() and I can read that ok as a query param but if user types it in directly with a period or tries `http://example.com/report;http://yourdomain.com` it doesn't work.  Also the semi colon would seem strange to most users (if it worked typing it in).

I have seen it possible on other site, for example: https://search.google.com/search-console/mobile-friendly?url=http://google.com this url works fine.

Am I coming up against a limit of Angular2s routing or is there a way this can be achieved?  Surely there is a way to allow period in a parameter at least

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier / cleaner to handle it like `/report/url.com`? i.e http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackoverflow.com

Comment: I have mentioned that in my post, it does not work.  Any route with a period in it wont work for me unless it is a query param

Comment: you want page to be integrated then go for iframes

Comment: I don't understand how iframe allows for this route

Comment: https://search.google.com/search-console/mobile-friendly?url=http://google.com on browser is realizing a GET request with an url-encoded param named 'url', with value http://google.com. As sure you know this Is one of the standard ways to realize GET requests (just retrieving data from server). I'm not used to Angular, but sure there's a very standard way that you can retrieve that param from url.

Comment: Simple encode your url before adding it to the route `encodeURIComponent(myUrl)`;

Comment: You did not read my question.  I want user to be able to follow that url by typing in browser (or by follow link).  If there is any period in route angular doesn't work